# How to get cell service signal strength in Android?

Tags: android, signals, rssi

I am trying to write a very simple Android application that checks the signal strength of the current cell.  So far, I have only found something called `getNeighboringCellInfo()`, but I'm not really sure if that includes the current cell.

How do I get the CURRENT cell signal strength in Android?

Does `getNeighborCellInfo()` get the current cell? It doesn't seem like it based on the results that I have been able to get with it.  Here's my current code:

```
List<NeighboringCellInfo> n = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();

//Construct the string
String s = "";
int rss = 0;
int cid = 0;
for (NeighboringCellInfo nci : n)
{
    cid = nci.getCid();
    rss = -113 + 2*nci.getRssi();
    s += "Cell ID: " + Integer.toString(cid) + "     Signal Power (dBm): " + 
            Integer.toString(rss) + "\n";
}

mainText.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

create a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and handle the onSignalStrengthChanged callback. When your app is initialized, it should give you an initial notification. This is in 1.x. in 2.x, there's an open [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4968) about this.

Comment: Any solution for 4.x - 8.x ?

Answer (score 14):

This code may help:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
public void onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean cfi) {}
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {}
public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {}
public void onDataActivity(int direction) {}
public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(boolean mwi) {}
public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {}
public void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu) {}
};
```

Once you’ve created your own Phone State Listener, register it with the Telephony Manager using a bitmask to indicate the events you want to listen for, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE |
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH);
```

Also, need to add these to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: `void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu)` is deprecated, use `void onSignalStrengthsChanged( SignalStrength signalStrength )` instead

Comment: @SamSch if you use onSignalStrengthsChanged you should also use PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS in the mask, instead of PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH

Comment: @Simone, yes, you're right. sorry that i missed that detail

Answer (score 0):

[image]Below code will create effect like picture (Android system Cell Info)

Inside your running activity/fragment, create a sub class like this

```
TextView txtSignalMobile1 = findViewById...;
    class myPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public int signalStrengthValue;
        public int signalLevel;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
                if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99)
                    signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() * 2 - 113;
                else{
                    signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getCellSignalStrengths().get(0).getDbm();
                    signalLevel =signalStrength.getCellSignalStrengths().get(0).getAsuLevel();
                }


            } else {
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            }
            txtSignalMobile1.setText(signalStrengthValue + "dbm, " + signalLevel + "asu");
        }
    }
```

Call somewhere else maybe onCreate or after a button... (used thread to update continnously value changed)

```
Thread splashThread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // update TextView here!
                                int signal2 = NetworkUtils.GetWifiSignal(requireContext());
                                txtSignalWifi.setText(signal2 + "/100");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    // when user exit suddenly
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread2.start();
```