# Current signal strength on Android device

Tags: android, telephony

Is there anyway to get current signal strength on Android device. I know there is a way where you can listen for signal strength change, but i cannot wait and need to know the current signal strength. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
B

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1967160/726863 -> When you implement the listener it should give you the current signal strength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the PhoneStateListener and save the last updated value into a variable and access it whenever you need it. It is the closest approximation of signal strenght you can get in real time.

Comment: thanks for info slezadav. So you mean, there is no way I can get current signal strength without waiting for it to change. If I save the last updated position, I need to keep it updating as it might be old. This does not solve my purpose. Thanks anyways for reply

Answer (score 0):

you can download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en
from the app store on your device and while you move in and out of an ssid it will show you the signal strength pretty accurately. Hope this helps. Cheers.