# How to get signal strength(rssi) value of main cell using android code?

Tags: android, android-intent, signal-strength

I want to get this information.For that I wrote following code but it is not works.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// for example value of first element
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
int Mrssi = cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

And is it possible to get this value for API level below 17? Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a PhoneStateListener and handle the onSignalStrengthChanged callback for this and override the method onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength).

You can find more information here...

[Get Signal Strength in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805880/get-signal-strength-in-android)

Comment: I want that whenever I click on button I will get current signal strength.I don't want that when the signal strength will be change it will show me.

Comment: @yogeshbhimani good luck getting it then. You have to create a PhoneStateListener in order to get the value below 17...