# Check for weak network availability

Tags: android, connection, android-volley, network-connection

I use **volley** and **asyntasks** to download data from a VPS and display it in fragments and activities. I encounter this error a lot when I am connected to a public network and the network signal is (very) weak. I use a simple network checking function in the app to display a toast when I am not connected to any network. In these cases the activities don't start and the Toast is displayed.
However, when I'm online and **the network signal is very weak**, the activity starts, Volley runs and throws an error

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to www.website.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (where Xs are the server address).
```

In this state of the app when I click on a navdrawer item it opens the activity and throws the same error.
This is how I check for connection:

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null) {
             Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
             return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(info.isConnected()) {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG," noninternet connection");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas on solving this error or upgrading my network checking function to check for weak network signal?

Comment: Gating operation at the front door is poor design, because even if the network is strong when you check it, the situation might be quite different even a split second later when you are trying to use it.  Don't require and assume, rather *deal with whatever actually happens*.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    DetailedState detailedState = info.getDetailedState();
    if(detailedState == DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK){
          // Your checks goes here  
    }
```

Please check this code. I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, but it requires API level 16.

Comment: yeah, what is your API requirement ?
then I think  info.isConnectedOrConnecting() can probably help you in knowing the current status of network.
Also if exception comes after opening activity , you can still dialog to user and close the activity by catching the exception.

Comment: I know but I want to prevent it. My minimum is API 14. `isConnectedOrConnecting() ` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another thread:

[Get Signal Strength in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805880/get-signal-strength-in-android)

```
public class myPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public int signalStrengthValue;

    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
            if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99)
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() * 2- 113;
            else
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        } else {
            signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
        }
        txtSignalStr.setText("Signal Strength : " + signalStrengthValue);
    }
}
```

So you can check the signal strength.