# Intent for signal reception lost

Tags: android

Is there any intent on Android that I can intercept when the phone signal reception is lost. All I can find is about the internet connection. I'd like to know when the signal reception gets lost.

If there is no intent for this, how can I get the information of a signal loss ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/26057844/3697191

Comment: Thanks, problem is that signal strength isn't reliable depending on the manufacturer of the phone. I have a few Samsung phones that always give me a signal strength of 0.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Actually I'd like to know when the phone signal is actually lost by the phone. When the reception level is at zero I'd like to catch the event in my background app. However every solution I see is based on analysing the reception strength and some devices don't return it properly. For exemple a Samsung phone of mine always return 0 as its signal strength so I can't consider it reliable.