# Get the overall signal strength in Android

Tags: android, signal-strength

I would like to get the overall signal strenght received with the mobile antenna. Ideally, I would love to get the electric field measured with my phone antenna.

I did found a lot of methods to get the signal strength but they all give a specific signal strenth (either GSM, Wifi, GPRS ...) but not the overall signal. Moreover, if there are no SIM card in the phone, the GSMsignalStrength will return 0 or null and even if there is a SIM card, I will only get the strength of the signal of that operator only.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805880/get-signal-strength-in-android