# Get signal strength level on app launch

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I know that you can listen to signal strength change to get signal level by creating a PhoneStateListener and handling the onSignalStrengthChanged callback for this and override the method onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength).

I want to know if you can trigger onSignalStrengthsChanged programmatically or is there any other way to get the signal strength level on app startup?

Thanks

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805880/get-signal-strength-in-android

Comment: @Manivasagam this solution is based on the onSignalStrengthChanged callback. It doesn't answer my question, getting the signal on app startup.