# how to get signal strength of sim network using Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

```
import * as application from 'application';
const TnsOneSignal = require('nativescript-onesignal').TnsOneSignal

if (application.android) {
        application.on(application.launchEvent, function(args: application.ApplicationEventData) {
            try {
                console.log('TnsOneSignal', TnsOneSignal)
                TnsOneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).init()
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error)
            }
        })
    }
```

I tried using above code and plugin but it does not work..

Can anyone help please with my code or provide better solution!

Comment: How does the plugin `nativescript-onesignal` relate to the SIM network strength? The plugin as far as I see provides a push notification functionality.

Comment: Yes you  are right as i m new in nativescript, so i didnt understand that but now i know it, so help me to get sim network strength if u could please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO get the signal strength of the current mobile phone you could use the native APIs on Android and iOS and convert the code to JavaScript based on the [NativeScript's marshaling rules](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/js-to-java).

For example, let's take this [native solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19805880/4936697). Here is how it would look like in NativeScript

```
let telephonyManager = application.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
let cellinfogsm = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
let cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Of course, in Android to be able to get this information you would need an explicit permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` so you could use [`nativescript-permissions` plugin](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-permissions) to grant them.

[Here you can find a test project](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/stackoverflow/signalStreinght) demonstrating the above technique. based on the same principle you could find an iOS example and convert the code to JS using the marshaling from Objective-C to JS.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I also wanna ask if any plugin need for this solution as in the first line application gives error: application not known??

Comment: `application` is in fact the application module  https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/blob/master/stackoverflow/signalStreinght/app/main-view-model.ts#L2

Comment: Note that the above code will work only on a real device and not on an emulator (where there is no SIM and telephone service)

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help Nick.