# How is telephony signal strength updated to UI in android

Tags: android, signal-strength

i went though the following post to get the signal strength in android:

[How to get cell service signal strength in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967136/how-to-get-cell-service-signal-strength-in-android)

my ques is that: how does the signal strength gets updated to the system UI. what does each bar in the strength meter signify? is there a particular threshold value for each bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getGsmLevel()` function in `SignalStrength.java` does the trick here:

```
int level;
int asu = getGsmSignalStrength();
if (asu <= 2 || asu == 99) level = SIGNAL_STRENGTH_NONE_OR_UNKNOWN;
else if (asu >= 12) level = SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GREAT;
else if (asu >= 8)  level = SIGNAL_STRENGTH_GOOD;
else if (asu >= 5)  level = SIGNAL_STRENGTH_MODERATE;
else level = SIGNAL_STRENGTH_POOR;
```

this function returns the `level`

Answer (score 2):

The signal strength icon is controlled from SystemUI. It might differ in other Android versions, but in KitKat the `NetworkController.java` class handles which icon is shown. The `SignalStrength.java` is the class that returns to `NetworkController.java` what the current signal strength is. The signal strength is represented as a number between 0 (no signal) and 4 (great signal). The actual signal is measured in dBm, and is passed into the `SignalStrength.java` class as a Parcel from the (low level) [radio interface layer (RIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Interface_Layer) of the Android framework. The actual thresholds differs between the different radio technologies used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @hanspeide. If i am not wrong, the function, 
updateTelephonySignalStrength() actually updates the strength to the signal icon in the UI.

Comment: Suppose we use WCDMA technology, and RIL sends a parcel to SignalStrength.java. Now this parcel contains a signal strength which is to be updated to the UI. How is it determined wether the strenght is low, medium or high?

Comment: SignalStrength.java does the conversion from dBm into a value from 0 to 4.